# How to make Gradle add Lombok to its Project and external dependencies libraries?

Tags: eclipse, gradle, lombok, buildship

I created a Java project in Eclipse Neon. I used Buildship 1.0.21 to import the project as a Gradle project and ran the `wrapper` and `init` commands to generate the build, settings and wrapper files.

The project has an empty source folder because I am trying to solve a similar problem on a more complicated project and taking the divide and conquer approach - just add Lombok dependency.

Here is my `build.gradle` as instructed on the lombok website:

```
apply plugin: 'java'

dependencies {
    compileOnly "org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.12"
}
```

and `gradle-wrapper.properties` if needed:

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-3.2.1-bin.zip /* <--- tried other versions too */
```

and I ran the jar file to install it on my eclipse. If I add the jar manually via "Java Build Path" it works but I want Gradle to handle this for me. When I refresh the project nothing happens - there is no lombok jar under "Projects and External Dependencies" and code relying on lombok will give errors.

There is another project I have which does have it there and I don't know what I did differently but I know it's possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to solve this after trial and error. The `build.gradle` file must add the `jcenter` repository:

```
repositories {
    jcenter()
}
```

Why this is the case and why this is not mentioned anywhere I don't know. But for now this is what works.