# Can't make gradle to import Lombok dependencies

Tags: java, gradle, lombok

According to [its documentation](https://github.com/franzbecker/gradle-lombok),

> A minimal build.gradle looks like this:
>
> ```
> plugins {
>   id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.10'
>   id 'java'
> }
>
> repositories {
>   jcenter() // or Maven central, required for Lombok dependency
> }
> ```
>
> After applying the plugin, the Lombok annotations can be used directly
>   in any Java code

This is my `build.gradle`

```
group 'tests'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok'

plugins {
    id 'io.franzbecker.gradle-lombok' version '1.10'
    id 'java'
}

lombok {
    version = "1.16.4"
    sha256 = "3ca225ce3917eac8bf4b7d2186845df4e70dcdede356dca8537b6d78a535c91e"
}

sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    jcenter() // https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41319176/how-to-make-gradle-add-lombok-to-its-project-and-external-dependencies-libraries
}

dependencies {
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.11'
}
```

When I run `gradle build`, it gives me

```
classpath
No dependencies

BUILD SUCCESSFUL
```

But the Lombok annotations are not available. I've also tried adding `compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.16.18'` under `dependencies`, with the same result. I understand that the plugin should have been applied. I'm using Intellij, but I don't think this has anything to do with the IDE, since the problem is not that the annotations are not recognized, but that they're not even available.

What am I missing?

Comment: What do you mean by ‘Lombok annotations are not available’? Does compilation fail? The Gradle run you just seems to do nothing at all.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in your `build.gradle`

```
apply plugin: 'java'

group = 'com.example'
version = '1.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok:1.18.4'
    testCompile group: 'junit', name: 'junit', version: '4.12'
}
```

Note that I'm using IntelliJ 2018.2 and have enabled annotations under 
`Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Compiler | Annotation Processors`.
If that does not work, then run `./gradlew clean build` from the command prompt and see if there's a build error.

If you don't see any errors then lombok can be used as follows

```
package com.example.java8;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class Country {
    private final String country_iso_code;
    private final String name;
}
```